# Prompt for Identity variable

Tags: powershell

I want to read-host -prompt the Bolded Security group so you can input any security group you would like in the field. But I can't figure out how to do it. Bonus if anyone can help me make the Group = the file name on export.

```
Get-AdGroupMember -Identity '**FIS-USR-ACS-CLT-Remote-Desktop-Horizon-View-AUX-W10**'-server pitt- 
  drdc-01.univ.pitt.edu | select-object SamAccountName| 
  Export-csv -Path c:\temp\FIS-USR-ACS-CLT-Remote-Desktop-Horizon-View-AUX-W10.csv  - 
  NoTypeInformation
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

`Read-Host` prompts the user to input a string, and then outputs said string - the easiest way to store the string is to just assign it to a variable:

```
$groupName = Read-Host -Prompt "Please input the target group name"
```

And then you simply substitute the hardcoded group name with said variable:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupName -Server pitt-drdc-01.univ.pitt.edu | Select-Object SamAccountName | Export-csv -Path "c:\temp\${groupName}.csv" - NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you! worked like a charm!